# Pseudonyms in memoir

Tags: memoir

I'd like to write a memoir about my unique teenage adventures growing up in another country. Since this was ~35 years ago, I don't remember very many names. Is it ok to use pseudonyms?  I presume that I would have to state that all referenced names are, in fact, made up.
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 4):

Yes, of course.

But perhaps you'd want to say 'I can't quite remember his name, let's call him x' or something along those lines.

**Make the reader aware that you are using a pseudonym** and you're fine. Good luck!